# Custom page numbering for appendix

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

For an appendix I want a page numbering which goes like A1, A2, ...

How to do that? With `\pagenumbering{...}` I can only choose between arabic and roman numbering.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can change the "appearance"  of the `page` counter by redefining `\thepage`. Here's a solution that simply adds "A":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\lipsum

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A\arabic{page}}
\appendix

\section{appfoo}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

For the `book` and `report` class, you may consider to add a page number prefix according to the apendix chapter "number" ("A", "B", ...). In the following example, the `etoolbox` package is used to prepend the definition of `\chapter` at the start of the appendix:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\lipsum

\appendix
\pretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter\arabic{page}}%
}{}{}

\chapter{appfoo}

\lipsum

\chapter{appbar}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. However, when I tried that it kinda messed up my Table of Contents. The page numbers are not properly aligned there anymore. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

For the `article` class I use the following in the `preamble` to get the page numbers to be A-1, A-2...B-1, B-2, etc. so you don't have to hardwire the section letter for each appendix. Including `\break` makes so that each appendix starts on its own page and gets a new page numbering style according to the section A, B, C, etc.

```
\newcommand{\appendixpagenumbering}{
  \break
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
}
```

Then use this command at the beginning of *each* appendix section

```
\appendixpagenumbering
```

This works nicely with the figure and table renumbering commands used once at the beginning of the appendix.

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

Comment: You could also add the clearpage, the redefinition of `thepage` and the pagenumbering to the definition of `\appendix`. Means less work and makes it more consistent.

Comment: *But*, i think using report would be a cleaner solution considering the clearpages. Ah and yeah, welcome :-)