# Customized page numbering in the Appendix

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

Hello lassies and lads!

I want to have customized numbering in my appendix. For example I want each page to be numbered as A.1, A.2, ..., A.n, for the first section, then B.1, B.2, ... for the second one etc.

I have prepared a minimal code where I show more or less how I can change the numbering, nonetheless, I am unable to do what I desire.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=0.00cm, height=0.00cm, left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in,     bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\author{Doge of the Serene Republic}    
\title{A Socio-economic Analysis of Naval Powers at the Italian Peninsula of the Medieval Period}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
This is my abstract ... 
\end{abstract}

\newpage


\section{This is section one}

\newpage
\section{On the Economic Structure of Venice and the Neighbouring Naval States}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\appendix

\section{The Scientific Method}
\par Here I describe my method in detail ...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that may do the things you want.  It takes care of figures, tables, equations, and pages, in terms of adding an appendix letter to the front.  And it does it for situations where you just want a lone (un-lettered) appendix ("Appendix") or when you want multiple lettered appendices ("Appendix A", "Appendix B", etc.)

EDITED to take Mico's advice.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\appendix{\@ifstar{\loneappendix}{\anappendix}}

\newcounter{appndx}
\setcounter{appndx}{0}

\newcommand \loneappendix [1]{
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{appndx}{1}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{appndx}-\@arabic\c@figure}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{table}}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \renewcommand\theequation {\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{equation}}
  \def\appendixtitle{\appendixname. #1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}\appendixtitle
  \theappendix\appendixtitle
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\Alph{appndx}.\arabic{page}}
}

\newcommand \anappendix[1]{
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{appndx}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{appndx}-\@arabic\c@figure}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand\theequation {\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{equation}}
  \def\appendixtitle{\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}. #1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}\appendixtitle
  \theappendix\appendixtitle
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\Alph{appndx}.\arabic{page}}
}
\newcommand\theappendix[1]{
  \section*{#1}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\bxtable[ht]{Caption}{\rule{2in}{1in}}
\section{Second Section}
Text
\begin{equation}
 y =x^2 
\end{equation}

\appendix{First of Many Appendices}
Let's see if tables are renumbered

\bxtable[ht]{Caption}{\rule{2in}{1in}}
\bxfigure[ht]{Caption}{\rule{2in}{1in}}

\begin{equation}
 y =x^2 
\end{equation}

I want to check if next page indexes page number

\clearpage

I see that it does.

\appendix{Second Lettered Appendix}

Is it ``B''?

Alternately, I could have called one single appendix:

\appendix*{My Lone Appendix}

The rest follows.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would prefer to have something like: Appendix A: and not Appendix   A.

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=0.00cm, height=0.00cm, left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in,     bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\author{Doge of the Serene Republic}    
\title{A Socio-economic Analysis of Naval Powers at the Italian Peninsula of the Medieval Period}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
This is my abstract ... 
\end{abstract}

\newpage


\section{This is section one}

\newpage
\section{On the Economic Structure of Venice and the Neighbouring Naval States}

\newpage
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % resets `page` counter to 1
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A.\arabic{page}}

\section{The Scientific Method}
\par Here I describe my method in detail ...

\end{document}
```

See also here: [Custom Appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59572/custom-page-numbering-for-appendix?rq=1)