# Change page numbering of appendices to A.1...B.1

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, page-numbering, appendices

I have 4 appendices (Syntax, Questionnaire, List of Abbreviations and the Bibliography). The page numbering is put to "Alph".

I would like to have just four letters A,B,C,D in my table of contents for each Appendix to appear (Syntax A, Questionnaire B, List of Abbreviations C and Bibliography D), even though almost every four of them has more than one page. So, I would like to have every follow-up page as A.1, A.2, respectively B.1, B.2 et cetera.

Can someone help me?

What I tried:

```
\appendix
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{B.\arabic{section}}
\input{./Appendices/Syntax}
\input{./Appendices/Questionnaire}
```

Comment: Revised Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132978/customized-page-numbering-in-the-appendix/132988#132988, but in the definition of `\anappendix`, use `\def\appendixtitle{#1 \Alph{appndx}}`.  Then upon invocation, use `\appendix{Syntax}`, etc.

Comment: Try replacing `\pagenumbering{Alph} \renewcommand{\thesection}{B.\arabic{section}}` with `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{page}{section} \makeatother \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection.\number\numexpr\arabic{page}+1}`

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: I'm using `article`. Sorry, I forgot to write it in the first place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the class is `book` and that no material will follow the appendices, here's an idea.

Add to `\appendix` a `\cleardoublepage` to ensure you're in a fresh state; then the command will redefine `\thepage` to have the appendix letter in front of the number. We also redefine `\chapter` from that point on to reset the page counter to 1.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy text

\preto\appendix{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter.\arabic{page}}%
  \preto\chapter{\cleardoublepage\setcounter{page}{1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter in main body}

\kant

\appendix

\chapter{Syntax}

\kant

\chapter{Questionnaire}

\kant

\chapter{List of Abbreviations}

\kant

\chapter{Bibliography}

\kant

\end{document}
```