# Page Numbering: Prime Numbers

Tags: page-numbering

I'm writing a project and would like each of my pages be numbered in terms of primes. That is, rather than 1,2,3,..., I'd like 2,3,5,.... I managed to find the following three pages:

- [How do i make custom page numbering in latex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753477/how-do-i-make-custom-page-numbering-in-latex)
- [recognizing prime (page) numbers in LaTeX](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/WpeYCWKubDk)
- [Custom page numbering for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59572/custom-page-numbering-for-appendix)

However, not being tech savvy, I have no idea how to use this. Just in case it makes a difference, I already know I need 49 pages and so I only need the first 49 primes (in case this let you define a set of some sort that it can utilise). Is there a way to do this without having to reset the counter on each page (which would require knowing where each page begins)?

Comment: I believe you mean "However, not being *TeX* savvy..." :)

Comment: Indeed I do. :P

Comment: Have you just read *The Curious Incident...* by Mark Haddon? :)

Comment: Believe it or not, my mother was an English teacher and, being unable to relate to mathematics in any way despite the fact I keep talking to her about it, she keeps using this book as an example. :P It was also that book that gave me the idea to number it in primes. So, yes. :P Amazing book.

Comment: For an added bonus why not do it in Mersenne Primes...? It might get tricky if your book is longer than 48 pages... :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image: prime pages 1]
[image: prime pages 2]
[image: prime pages 3]
[image: prime pages 4]
[image: prime pages 5]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\nthprime}[1]{%
  \ifcase #1\relax
  \or 2\or 3\or 5\or 7\or 11\or 13\or 17\or 19\or 23\or 29\or 31\or
  37\or 41\or 43\or 47\or 53\or 59\or 61\or 67\or 71\or 73\or 79\or 
  83\or 89\or 97\or 101\or 103\or 107\or 109\or 113\or 127\or 131\or 
  137\or 139\or 149\or 151\or 157\or 163\or 167\or 173\or 179\or 181\or 
  191\or 193\or 197\or 199\or 211\or 223\or 227\or 229\or 233\or 239\or
  241\or 251\else 997\fi }
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\nthprime{\value{page}}}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newcount\cnta
\cnta1
\loop
\section{a section}
\lipsum[\cnta-\numexpr\cnta+3\relax]
\advance\cnta 4
\ifnum\cnta < 50
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: What??!!  You're not going to calculate the primes on the fly?? ;^)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you made me laugh. `;-)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the reason was due to an hesitation to again use `xint` in an answer here, or rather  `xinttools` as only short integers are needed, and without it I feel unarmed...

Comment: If you change your mind, various answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134305/how-to-produce-a-list-of-prime-numbers-in-latex might help.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I contributed [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96001/4686](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96001/4686) and I think one more perhaps which I can't find right now. Notice that quite probably none of these answers are expandable, and I were to do it again, I would do it expandably... `;-)` (look at the `\edef` on page 53 of `xint.pdf`)

Comment: Ok, so I've just run this code and it works. You have made me one of the happiest mathematicians in the world! So, thank you. :D

Comment: @user60126 you are welcome! hope your readers will know the list by heart then. Although you will have to inform them it never stops `;-)`.

Answer (score 26):

Today I have already answered a similar [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question ["Output the first 200 primes using TeX"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23758/16143).

My [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23766/16143) needs 176 bytes to print the first 200 prime numbers with plain TeX. I have ungolfed the code and adapted it to LaTeX. As interface `\primenumber`/`\primecounter` are added as equivalents to `\@alph`/`\alph`. Internally the prime numbers are stored in macros `\prime@<number>`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \countdef\i=1 %
  \countdef\j=2 %
  \countdef\k=3 %
  \countdef\ii=4 %
  \newcount\prime@count
  \prime@count=1 %
  \global\@namedef{prime@1}{2}%
  \i=3
  \loop
  \ifnum\prime@count<200 %
    {% group with curly braces because of the nested \loop
      % Test for all 2 <= j < i: trunc(i/j)*j == i
      % If true, then j is divisor of i and i is not prime
      \j=3
      % small optimization, \ii should be sqrt(i),
      % it is approximated by \ii/3 + 1
      \ii=\i
      \divide\ii 3
      \advance\ii\@ne
      \let\x.%
      \loop
      \ifnum\j<\ii
        \k=\i
        \divide\k \j
        \multiply\k \j
        \ifnum\k=\i
          \let\iterate\@empty
          \let\x!%
        \fi
        \advance\j\tw@
      \repeat
      \ifx\x.%
        \global\advance\prime@count\@ne
        \expandafter\xdef\csname prime@\the\prime@count\endcsname{\the\i}%
      \fi
    }%
    \advance\i\tw@ % test next odd number
  \repeat
\endgroup

\newcommand*{\primenumber}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{prime@\number#1}\@ctrerr{\csname prime@\number#1\endcsname}%
}
\newcommand*{\primecounter}[1]{%
  \primenumber{\csname c@#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \newcounter{test}
  \renewcommand*{\thetest}{\primecounter{test}}

  \setcounter{test}{1}
  \makeatletter
  \@whilenum\value{test}<\prime@count\do{%
    \thetest, %
    \stepcounter{test}%
  }%
  \primenumber{\prime@count}%
  \makeatother

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 11):

You can find a precompiled list of 10000 prime numbers, so there's no need to compute them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\PRIME}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_prime_list_seq { \int_use:c { c@#1 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_prime_list_seq
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_space:n  {`\ }
\seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_prime_list_seq { ~ } 
 {% a longer list is found at http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt
      2      3      5      7     11     13     17     19     23     29 
     31     37     41     43     47     53     59     61     67     71 
     73     79     83     89     97    101    103    107    109    113 
    127    131    137    139    149    151    157    163    167    173 
    179    181    191    193    197    199    211    223    227    229 
    233    239    241    251    257    263    269    271    277    281 
    283    293    307    311    313    317    331    337    347    349 
    353    359    367    373    379    383    389    397    401    409 
    419    421    431    433    439    443    449    457    461    463 
    467    479    487    491    499    503    509    521    523    541 
    547    557    563    569    571    577    587    593    599    601 
    607    613    617    619    631    641    643    647    653    659 
    661    673    677    683    691    701    709    719    727    733 
    739    743    751    757    761    769    773    787    797    809 
    811    821    823    827    829    839    853    857    859    863 
    877    881    883    887    907    911    919    929    937    941 
    947    953    967    971    977    983    991    997   1009   1013 
   1019   1021   1031   1033   1039   1049   1051   1061   1063   1069 
   1087   1091   1093   1097   1103   1109   1117   1123   1129   1151 
   1153   1163   1171   1181   1187   1193   1201   1213   1217   1223 
   1229   1231   1237   1249   1259   1277   1279   1283   1289   1291 
   1297   1301   1303   1307   1319   1321   1327   1361   1367   1373 
   1381   1399   1409   1423   1427   1429   1433   1439   1447   1451 
   1453   1459   1471   1481   1483   1487   1489   1493   1499   1511 
   1523   1531   1543   1549   1553   1559   1567   1571   1579   1583 
   1597   1601   1607   1609   1613   1619   1621   1627   1637   1657 
   1663   1667   1669   1693   1697   1699   1709   1721   1723   1733 
   1741   1747   1753   1759   1777   1783   1787   1789   1801   1811
}
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOn

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\PRIME{page}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\ExplSyntaxOn % just to fill contents
\prg_replicate:nn { 30 } { \section{A} x \newpage }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why do just what we *need*? what about fun?