# Page Numbering Using Only Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: page-numbering, calculations

How to display the page number in Fibonacci.
Example:
Normal page number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,...

Fibonnacci page number style: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  This looks very much like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164984/15925, and may well get closed as a duplicate of that.  In any case we usually ask that you show what you have tried and include some sample code.  If you don't have success modifying the code there, then please update your question saying what is giving you difficulties.

Comment: ...........why?

Answer (score 16):

Package `fibnum` helps:

```
\usepackage{fibnum}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\fibnum{\value{page}}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fibnum}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\fibnum{\value{page}}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\test}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Page value: & \the\value{page}\\
    \texttt{\textbackslash thepage}: & \thepage
  \end{tabular}%
  \newpage
}
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\end{document}
```

If the number of pages is large (>> 46), then `\fibnumPreCalc` should be used to get a more efficient `\fibnum`. `\fibnum` must calculate the numbers each time, unless the values are calculated in advance via `\fibnumPreCalc`.
Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fibnum}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\fibnum{\value{page}}}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \fibnumPreCalc{\value{page}}%
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\test}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Page value: & \the\value{page}\\
    \texttt{\textbackslash thepage}: & \thepage
  \end{tabular}%
  \newpage
}
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\setcounter{page}{200}
\test
\end{document}
```

Table in last page:

> [image: Result 200]

The package `fibnum` calculates and stores the first 46 Fibonacci numbers, because these numbers also fit into a TeX count register. However the numbers are not limited by this,
as the previous example has shown. Above this value package `fignum` switches its calculation method by using the expandable operations for big integers of package `bigintcalc`.

Answer (score 8):

Two solutions.

## With Binet's formula

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3cm,paperheight=4cm,textheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_const:Nn \c_rudstep_phi_fp { (sqrt(5)+1)/2 } % the golden ratio

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\fibonacci}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n
   {
    round( ( ( \c_rudstep_phi_fp)^(#1) - (1 - \c_rudstep_phi_fp)^(#1) ) / sqrt(5) , 0 )
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\fibonacci{\value{page}}}

\begin{document}

a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage
a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage

\end{document}
```

***Note:*** the rounding operation guarantees a good result only for 68 pages. Indeed `\fibonacci{68}` returns 72723460248141, which is correct; on the other hand `\fibonacci{69}` returns 117669030460995, while the correct value is 117669030460994. No number returned thereafter is correct.

## With the recursive formula

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3cm,paperheight=4cm,textheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\newcounter{twoback}
\newcounter{oneback}
\setcounter{twoback}{0}
\setcounter{oneback}{1}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \setcounter{page}{\numexpr\value{twoback}+\value{oneback}-1}% page is stepped later
  \setcounter{twoback}{\value{oneback}}%
  \setcounter{oneback}{\numexpr\value{page}+1}%
}

\begin{document}

a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage
a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage

\end{document}
```

***Note:*** This method will produce the correct number until the Fibonacci number is less than 2<sup>31</sup>, that is in the range of TeX integers. Thus only 46 pages are supported.

This limitation can be overcome by using jfbu's package `xint`, with basically the same method that doesn't compute anew the number, but just applies the recursive definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3cm,paperheight=4cm,textheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xint,atbegshi}

\newcommand\twoback{0}
\newcommand\oneback{1}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \oodef\temp{\xintiiAdd{\twoback}{\oneback}}%         
  \global\let\thepage\temp
  \global\let\twoback\oneback
  \global\let\oneback\temp
}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\thepage{1}}% initialize, just to be on the safe side

\begin{document}

a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage
a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage a\newpage

\end{document}
```

## Output of both

Note that the setting with `geometry` is not relevant.

[image]

---

As of September 22, 2014, a new package is available: `bnumexpr`, that allows for a more natural notation. So instead of `xint` one can load `bnumexpr` and change the code above into

```
\usepackage{bnumexpr,atbegshi}

\newcommand\twoback{0}
\newcommand\oneback{1}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \edef\temp{\thebnumexpr\twoback+\oneback\relax}%
  \global\let\thepage\temp
  \global\let\twoback\oneback
  \global\let\oneback\temp
}
% initialize, just to be on the safe side; the second is easier ;-)
%\AtBeginDocument{\edef\thepage{\thebnumexpr\twoback+\oneback\relax}}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\thepage{1}}
```

Comment: You really like the LaTeX3 FPU, don't you :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, of course. ;-) I added the limitations.

Comment: Perhaps we need to ship a big-integer module for `expl3` to handle these cases :-)

Comment: It is a honor for `xintexpr` to relay `l3fp` beyond `16` digits of precision... for people not otherwise needing `\xintexpr` it is enough to only load `xint` rather than `xintexpr` and then `\oodef\temp{\xintiiAdd{\twoback}{\oneback}}` rather than `\fdef\temp{\xintthe\xintexpr\twoback+\oneback\relax}`. For people who wonder: `\oodef` and `\fdef` are wrappers around `\def`, defined in package `xint`, they apply some type of expansion to the argument of the macro, in the case at hand it achieves the same result as if using `\edef`, with a minuscule gain in time.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for the suggestion. Your packages are indeed amazing.

Comment: thanks... in my previous comment I mistyped `\xintexpr` where your original and correct `\xintiiexpr` was meant, sorry. I did some additional work on `\xintexpr` in June, and your comment encourages me to work towards releasing it sometime soon.

Comment: @jfbu I was serious about a 'bigint' module for `expl3`: I might take a look at your code if you've sorted expressions (we have single big ints but not expressions, and the latter would be nice for symmetry). Note of course the like most FPUs `l3fp` doesn't claim or aim to go beyond a certain number of places of precision.

Comment: To be clear, I'm thinking of expressions of the same form as allowed by `\numexpr` (and so `\int_eval:n`), not any further 'stuff'.

Comment: @JosephWright currently `\xintiiexpr` works with big ints, `+`, `-`, `*` and maps therein `/` to the Euclidean division (which truncates; rounding could be chosen instead). But it has more stuff than `\numexpr`: it knows `^` for power, it has `max` and `min` also `gcd` and `lcm` for multiple arguments, it knows `sqrt` for truncated square root... it knows boolean operation (development version uses `&&` and `||` notation like in l3fp). Although only macros from `xint` are needed, `\xintiiexpr` is in package `xintexpr` which loads all the extra stuff in `xintfrac` dealing with fractions.

Comment: @jfbu Yes, I'd seen that `xintexpr` covers many things. What I was trying to get at is that for an `expl3` implementation, expressions would be nice but would presumably be set up to match what can be done by (most obviously) `\numexpr`. That means on `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` as 'native' operations, with `/` rounding and a separate `\bigint_div_truncate:n`. [I'm thinking we should look at this for `expl3` as the idea is we are aiming to cover what people commonly need in programming, and _I_ need big integers for `siunitx` :-)]

Comment: @JosephWright (side note: development version has some new style when expandably branching which will make the code more readable.) Does `bigint` module for `expl3` want as Heiko's `bigintcalc` or my `xint` deal with arbitrarily big integers, or say, up to 64 or 96 digits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17294/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-jfbu).

Comment: @jfbu I added a mention and code for the new `bnumexpr` package

Comment: @egreg after some procrastination I am adding `l3bigint` option to package `bnumexpr`. Somehow I got afraid it would be complicated to install `l3bigint` but  I was wrong.