# Appendix page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

I'm new to latex , but things for me are easier since i've a partner that guides me to work on my thesis, but this he doesn't know.
So... i'm trying to number the pages of the appendices like: A1,A2 . so i tried to follow all the questions that already been asked and it works partially. For example i have 6 pages of appendix A and it is numbered correctly up till page 5 i.e A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 but page 6 just showing the # 6. 
This solution i tried:

[Custom page numbering for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59572/custom-page-numbering-for-appendix)

this is a link to my pdf file

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/451295/main1.pdf

if i have to send my code just tell me

thx in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Odd are, something happened on page 6 to reset \thepage, so yeah we'll need a MWE (perhaps just page 6).

Comment: what should I include in the question that help you to see the problem ?

Comment: if i had to guess, i'd ask if page 6 is the last page of the appendix.  i've seen a similar situation in which code activated at `\end{document}` altered the expected value of the running head.  but more information (in the form of a non-working example) is needed to diagnose that.

Comment: Currently pg.6 is the last one , but i added random text to create another page and it didn't change still A-1,A-2...6,7(new page). Can I just copy paste my "main.tex" file and the "appendix.tex" file ? or upload it to and attach a link for you to check it ?\

Comment: I don't know if it is the solution but i write at the end of the appendix.tex file \clearpage. now it works, but how it will affect my document ?

Answer (score 4):

Very likely you are doing a local redefinition of `\thepage` in a group. If the group closes, but there is yet material, then the `\clearpage` of `\end{document}` ships out the last page with the old meaning of `\thepage`.
BTW, also an environment acts as group.

Possible solutions/workarounds:

- A global definition of `\thepage` helps:

  ```
  \gdef\thepage{A\arabic{page}}
  ```
- Or an explicit `\clearpage` before the group closes to output the last page in the scope of the redefined `\thepage`.